# Ext 4 chart: Highlight line when mouseover line not just over marker?

Tags: extjs, charts

I have a chart with a line series, with a highlight configured, markers are not shown.

With some data, the markers are far enough apart from each other that when mousing over the line it may or may not highlight depending on how close the mouse cursor is to a (hidden) marker.  Because markers are not shown, this gives the appearance that the highlghting when hovering the mouse over the line is random and broken; sometimes it highlights, sometimes it doesn't.

I tried increasing selectionTolerance, but this isn't acceptable as that is essentially a radius around the marker, such that hovering farther and farther away from the marker causes the line to highlight when the mouse cursor isn't even close to the line.

So, I want a small selectionTolerance so the mouse has to be close to the line, but I want the highlight to be applied when the mouse is close to the **line**, not just when it is close to a (hidden) **marker**.

How to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Edit: upon looking further, I believe the answer is for me to overload the **isItemInPoint** function for Ext.chart.series.Line. In my case, I only want the line to highlight when hovering over the line when showMarkers is false. When ShowMarkers is true, the current behavior is acceptable. So, it should be a pretty clean override. Still have to figure out how to determine if a point is on the line, and which item to return, but that's probably just a matter of some maths.

Comment: Will you please post a sample of your code illustrating the problem? Sencha has a fiddle site that would work nicely.

Comment: This example has the markers shown, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JPEEv/151/) but you can easily add showMarkers:false to the series config. Regardless of whether markers are shown or not, the line only highlights when near the marker.
Hover over the 1997 data point (marker). The entire line highlights. Now, use the mouse cursor and trace along the series line. Whenever you trace close enough to a marker the line highlights, but then unhighlights as you continue along the line.  I wish for the line to be highlighted whenever the mouse cursor is on the line, not just when it is on a marker.

Comment: Sorry. just learning mini-Markdown now. The example is here: [http://jsfiddle.net/JPEEv/151/](http://jsfiddle.net/JPEEv/151/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's what I ended up doing, and it works as desired. I extended chart.series.line into betterline. Then I make my series type "betterline" and set lineSelectionTolerance in the config as well.

```
Ext.define('MyExtends.SeriesLine', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.series.Line',
    alias: ['series.betterline', 'Ext.chart.series.BetterLine'],
    type: 'betterline',
    isItemInPoint: function (x, y, item, i)
    {
        var me = this,
             items = me.items,
             ln = items.length,
             tolerance = me.selectionTolerance,
             prevItem,
             nextItem,
             prevPoint,
             nextPoint,
             x1, x2,
             y1, y2,
             dist1, dist2, dist,
             sqrt = Math.sqrt;

        nextItem = items[i];
        prevItem = i && items[i - 1];

        if (i >= ln)
        {
            prevItem = items[ln - 1];
        }
        prevPoint = prevItem && prevItem.point;
        nextPoint = nextItem && nextItem.point;
        x1 = prevItem ? prevPoint[0] : nextPoint[0] - tolerance;
        y1 = prevItem ? prevPoint[1] : nextPoint[1];
        x2 = nextItem ? nextPoint[0] : prevPoint[0] + tolerance;
        y2 = nextItem ? nextPoint[1] : prevPoint[1];
        dist1 = sqrt((x - x1) * (x - x1) + (y - y1) * (y - y1));
        dist2 = sqrt((x - x2) * (x - x2) + (y - y2) * (y - y2));
        dist = Math.min(dist1, dist2);

        if (dist <= tolerance)
        {
            return dist == dist1 ? prevItem : nextItem;
        }

        if (me.lineSelectionTolerance)
        {
            if (prevItem && nextItem && prevItem != nextItem)
            {
                tolerance = me.lineSelectionTolerance;
                x1 = parseFloat(prevPoint[0]);
                y1 = parseFloat(prevPoint[1]);
                x2 = parseFloat(nextPoint[0]);
                y2 = parseFloat(nextPoint[1]);

                if (x > x1 && x < x2)
                {
                    var slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
                    var slopePerp = -1 / slope;

                    var xIntercept = (x2 * (x * slopePerp - y + y1) + x1 * (x * -slopePerp + y - y2)) / (slopePerp * (x2 - x1) + y1 - y2);
                    var yIntercept = slopePerp * xIntercept - slopePerp * x + y;
                    if (!(y2 - y1)) // Horizontal line
                    {
                        xIntercept = x;
                        yIntercept = y1;
                    }
                    var a = (x - xIntercept);
                    var b = (y - yIntercept);
                    var distPointToIntercept = sqrt(a * a + b * b); // Pythagorean

                    if (distPointToIntercept < tolerance)
                    {
                        dist1 = sqrt((xIntercept - x1) * (xIntercept - x1) + (yIntercept - y1) * (yIntercept - y1));
                        dist2 = sqrt((xIntercept - x2) * (xIntercept - x2) + (yIntercept - y2) * (yIntercept - y2));
                        dist = Math.min(dist1, dist2);

                        return dist == dist1 ? prevItem : nextItem;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```